# Laravel 5 Production Migrations -- Unable to Disable Migration Warning

Tags: laravel-5, deployment, migration, production-environment

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel website in production mode. The site is currently deployed, but I've added a database and some migrations plus seeds, and the deployment for the migrations is failing.

The logs are showing me that the Migrations fail because the production mode brings up a prompt that says

```
Migrating the database tables into your application
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > 

  Aborted
```

I've tried working around this by piping "yes" into the migration command in my deploy script, but it did't work. Presumably I could change the mode to NOT production, but I don't think that's an appropriate fix here. I also tried using the "--force" flag for migrations but it didn't prevent the warning.

**deploy script**

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install
composer require nesbot/carbon:1.26.3
composer require tcg/voyager
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
npm run development
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.2-fpm reload

if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan voyager:install
    php artisan migrate --force
    php artisan db:seed --class=CategoriesTableSeeder --force
    php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTable --force
    php artisan db:seed --class=BlogPostsTableSeeder --force
fi
```

Does anyone know how I can disable this warning in production or why the force option isn't suppressing this warning so I can run the migrations?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `php artisan migrate --pretend`, answer with 'yes' and see if the proposed sql commands roll out. Then at least you'll know if it is laravel aborting or your database that refuses altering existing tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `--no-interaction` flag as well, but it looks like what you have there (`--force`) is right.  Are you sure nothing else is running your migration, for instance does `voyager:install` auto-run migrations, or `post-install` script in composer?

Also just interested, why you are installing packages in your Forge deployment script. They should be included in the repo in the `package.lock` or `composer.lock` files so you just need to run `install`.

Comment: I ran the command with "--no-interaction" it cancelled without even asking, is there a environment variable through which the response can be set?

Comment: The docs itself mentioned that the command should run with --force flag in case you don't want the interaction, this solution seems like a hack, since force is something which prevents many security checks which is not at all recommended in the production level things.

Not sure how dangerous it is to use --force flag from a security perspective, probably the name of the flag should change or a new flag should be introduced to prevent such interaction so that things can happen in automation environment

Answer (score 2):

you can answer yes or no to that interaction, ex:

```
yes | php artisan migrate
```